# Liferay Embedded portlet does not call render function

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

I have looked everywhere for this bug and I have seen no other issue

Currently I am using Liferay 7.0 and I  embedded my portlet in a web content template like so:

```
 <div class ="container-fluid">
        <div class ="row">
            <div class ="col-md-6 col-sm-6">

         <#assign VOID = freeMarkerPortletPreferences.setValue("portletSetupPortletDecoratorId", "barebone") />
       <@liferay_portlet["runtime"]
             defaultPreferences="${freeMarkerPortletPreferences}"
             portletProviderAction=portletProviderAction.VIEW
             portletName="foo" />
             ${freeMarkerPortletPreferences.reset()}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Portlet works fine outside of the freemarker template, however inside it actionRequest button is called but it never enters render function so the buttons I set do nothing.

Is there any special requirement for a portlet to be put inside a freemarker template? Did I forget anything?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are [embedding by portletName](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/embedding-portlets-in-themes-and-layout-templates) so it can be either:

Instanceable, and then you need to provide its instance ID, as:

> ```
>  instanceId="INSTANCE_ID"
> ```

If not, set `com.liferay.portlet.instanceable=false`

> If your portlet is instanceable, an instance ID must be provided; otherwise, you can remove this line. To set your portlet to non-instanceable, set the property `com.liferay.portlet.instanceable` in the component annotation of your portlet to `false`.

Comment: it's not instanceable. But tried with instance and instanceId as well in some debugging times

Comment: the portlet shows up it just does not call render method. Nor render request functions. Action requests are working fine

Comment: If a portlet shows up, it's rendered. If you can't hit any breakpoint or log message within that portlet's render method, make sure that the deployed code matches your expectation.